# datetimepicker disabled past date does not show

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I am using [**`bootstrap datetimepicker`**](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/). in this plugins I am not able show past date in input box when I will update the disabled date. anyone have any idea how to resolving this issue ??

Comment: Question isn't clear.. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: my datetimepicker input box is in readonly mode. when I am submit the data that time data store successfully in database. as well show in grid also. when i will update particular grid data that time data load in bootstrap modal popup and datepicker input box is blank but when I will focus on input box that time datetimepicker is open and select the new date but I cant show actual date.

Comment: You need to provide some code then to actually see what are you upto..

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting **startDate** or **minDate** attribute?
It may look like this in your code,

```
$('#date').datepicker({ 
    startDate: new Date() 
});
```

You can remove it or try with past date from when you need to enable the selection.

Comment: no I am not add any attribute. but in the function setting I am add the start date and it's work fine but not set actual date which is set in data grid.